# Erro: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo

Venho da linguagem C e estou tentando fazer a soma dos valores de uma lista.
Mas após declarar não consigo usar a função `sum()` e os demais métodos. O Python me retorna que posso apenas fazer operação em números inteiros.

Checando o tipo da lista me retorna `list`.

Meu código:

```py
var = [0,0,0]
soma = 1
for x in range(3):
    print("Digite o valor",x+1)
    var[x] = input()

for var in var:
    soma += var
```

O erro levantado:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str

Comment: O retorno da função `input` **sempre** é uma string, você precisa converter para inteiro antes de utilizá-lo.

Comment: @phduarte Sobre a edição: não precisa colocar o nome da linguagem depois do `\`\`\`` pois o sistema já usa as tags da pergunta para saber qual é a linguagem e aplica o syntax highlight correto (e como já tinha a tag [tag:python], então já estava tudo certo - só faria sentido se o bloco de código fosse em outra linguagem (diferente das tags da pergunta) ou quando a pergunta tem mais de uma tag de linguagem - o que não era o caso). Veja mais em https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/401803

Comment: ótima dica @hkotsubo. obrigado! No caso da linguagem ser explicitada, isso causa prejuízo de algum nível?

Comment: @phduarte Nesse caso acho que não faz diferença, o highlight será o mesmo (o que é mais um motivo para não precisar fazer esse tipo de edição, pois não é necessário) :-)

Comment: O senhor está certíssimo. Valeu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que acontece é que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string, e você tentou somar essas strings com o número que está em `soma`. Então você deve usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter a string em número.

Mas tem outros detalhes. Não precisa declarar a lista com valores quaisquer, pois ela pode começar vazia e você vai adicionando os elementos conforme vão sendo lidos.

E o `input` aceita como parâmetro a mensagem, então não precisa imprimir ela antes.

Ficaria assim:

```
numeros = []
for x in range(1, 4):
    numeros.append(int(input(f"Digite o valor {x}")))

soma = 0
for n in numeros:
    soma += n

# ou se quiser usar o que já tem pronto
soma = sum(numeros)
```

Também mudei o `range` para ir de 1 a 3, assim você não precisa somar 1 ao imprimir.

Repare que a soma deve começar em zero, e não em 1. Mas isso só se você quiser calcular manualmente, pois já existe a função [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) que faz isso para você.

Quanto ao `for var in var` do seu código: confesso que fiquei surpreso ao ver que isso funciona, mas de qualquer forma eu não usaria uma variável do *loop* com o mesmo nome da lista, pois isso só deixa o código mais confuso.

---

Só pra constar, outra forma de criar a lista é usando [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
numeros = [ int(input(f"Digite o valor {x}")) for x in range(1, 4) ]
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 2):

isso ocorre devido **python** ser uma **linguagem de tipagem dinâmica e forte**. Utilize o método `int()` para converter o valor digitado pelo usuário (que é do tipo `str/string`) para atribuí-lo ao *array* que guarda um conjunto de `int`:

```py
var = [0,0,0]
soma = 1
for x in range(3):
    print("Digite o valor",x+1)
    var[x] = int(input())

for var in var:
    soma += var
```