# Não sei o que fazer, estou fazendo uma tabela de resultados para um exercicio e fala que está dando erro na linha 4

Tags: python

```
a = input ('Primeiro número: ') 
b = input ('Segundo número: ')
c = a+b
d = a-b
e = a*b
f = a**b
g = a//b
h = a%b

print('a = ' , a , '\nb = ' , b , '\na + b = ', c , '\na - b = ', d , '\na * b = ', e , '\na ** b = ', f , '\na // b = ', g , '\na % b = ' , h)
```

Quando eu executo e coloco os dois números, aparece a isso:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):**
>
> **File "C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/Python/lição 1.py", line 4, in
>
> d = a-b**
>
> **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'**

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Erro: unsupported operand type(s)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/489243/erro-unsupported-operand-types)

Comment: dup: [Exercício Gasto de Combustível em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401522/exerc%c3%adcio-gasto-de-combust%c3%advel-em-python)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Oque está errado é que está retornando para o programa abaixo em forma de `string` é necessário retornar em `int` ou `float`.

```
#Função int() serve para converter números de string(str) para inteiros (int).

a = int(input('Primeiro número: ')) #Convertendo oque o usuario digitou de str para int
b = int(input('Segundo número: ')) #Mesmo processo de cima.
c = a+b
d = a-b
e = a*b
f = a**b
g = a//b
h = a%b

print(f'A = {a} B = {b} \nA + B = {c}; \nA - B = {d}; \nA.B = {e}; \nA^B = {f}; \nA // B = {g}; \nA / B = {h}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa converter a entrada para algum tipo numérico. Pois o padrão é retornar `string`

```
# a função float abaixo faz a conversão de tipos
a = float(input ('Primeiro número: '))
b = float(input ('Segundo número: '))
c = a+b
d = a-b
e = a*b
f = a**b
g = a//b
h = a%b

print('a = ' , a , '\nb = ' , b , '\na + b = ', c , '\na - b = ', d , '\na * b = ', e , '\na ** b = ', f , '\na // b = ', g , '\na % b = ' , h)
```